# Failed to start the Kernel. Cannot run Jupyter Notebook in VS Code for Windows. Issue with Traitlets

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, pyzmq, python-traitlets

I am trying to run a Jupyter Notebook in VS Code for Windows and running into an issue with traitlets. Can anyone help?

Following steps to re-create:

1. Start new Python virtual environment.
2. Create new Jupyter Notebook (.ipynb file)
3. Open file in VS Code for Windows and select virtual environment's interpreter.
4. Try and run `print('hello')` in the first kernel.

The error message I get:

```
Failed to start the Kernel. 
c:\Users\XX\python_projects\demo_issue\myenv\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2202: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around strings is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. You can use 'hmac-sha256' instead of '"hmac-sha256"' if you require traitlets >=5.
  warn(
c:\Users\XX\python_projects\demo_issue\myenv\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2157: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around Bytes is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. Use '7518421c-2675-406f-81c8-3e4a669b0c20' instead of 'b"7518421c-2675-406f-81c8-3e4a669b0c20"'.
  warn(
Bad file descriptor (C:\projects\libzmq\src\epoll.cpp:100). 
View Jupyter log for further details.
```

I have tried to install an earlier version of traitlets (`python -m pip install traitlets<5 --force-reinstall`) but it creates dependency conflicts:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
ipython 8.3.0 requires traitlets>=5, but you have traitlets 4.3.3 which is incompatible.
ipykernel 6.13.0 requires traitlets>=5.1.0, but you have traitlets 4.3.3 which is incompatible.
```

And I also get this error under the kernel:

```
The file 'myenv\lib\site-packages\traitlets\utils\__init__.py' seems to be overriding built in modules and interfering with the startup of the kernel. Consider renaming the file and starting the kernel again.
Click here for more info.
```

Here is a screenshot of the main issue, in case helpful.
[image]

Does anyone how any ideas of how I might fix? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for any help you can give!

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

I followed this part of the original error message for a solution:

```
Bad file descriptor (C:\projects\libzmq\src\epoll.cpp:100).
```

Installing an earlier version for pyzmq seemed to address the issue for now:

```
python -m pip install pyzmq==19.0.2 --force-reinstall
```

Although it still gives this warning:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
jupyter-client 7.3.0 requires pyzmq>=22.3, but you have pyzmq 19.0.2 which is incompatible.
```

Comment: Downgrading pyzmq failed for me. However, upgrading (to 24.0.1 in my case) did work:
python -m pip install -U pyzmq